# java.lang.NullPointerException occurs when i update?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I got Null pointer exception
`"java.lang.NullPointerException"`
refer below code for reference
Everything should be fine but not able to update data to the database(mySql)

```
<% try{
        //reading request parameters

          String projectName=request.getParameter("projectName").trim();
          String status=request.getParameter("status").trim();

          //String user = session.getAttribute("user").toString();
          Connection connection = DAO.getConnection();
          PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("update project set status=? where projectName=?");

          pstmt.setString(1,status);
          pstmt.executeUpdate();                    
          out.println("<h2 style='color:green'>Project Status has been updated</h2>");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          out.println("<h2 style='color:red'>Please login to update your Status</h2>");
    }
%>
```

Not able to update because of exception
refer below
Please anyone suggest me how to solve this exception...

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at org.apache.jsp.MyWorkPanelAction_jsp._jspService(MyWorkPanelAction_jsp.java:93)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 1):

You missed the projectName...Try the code below

```
try{
        //reading request parameters

          String projectName=request.getParameter("projectName").trim();
          String status=request.getParameter("status").trim();

          //String user = session.getAttribute("user").toString();
          Connection connection = DAO.getConnection();
          PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("update project set status=? where projectName=?");

          pstmt.setString(1,status);
          pstmt.setString(2,projectName); //Try this

          pstmt.executeUpdate();                    
          out.println("<h2 style='color:green'>Project Status has been updated</h2>");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
          ex.printStackTrace();
          out.println("<h2 style='color:red'>Please login to update your Status</h2>");
    }
```